# Label every nth seconds of a pandas dataframe by an incremental value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, time-series

I have a dataframe include ID and time

| ID | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-31 23:59:53 |
| 2 | 2022-07-31 23:59:54 |
| 3 | 2022-07-31 23:59:55 |
| 4 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2022-07-31 00:00:01 |
| 6 | 2022-07-31 00:00:02 |
| 7 | 2022-07-31 00:00:07 |
| 8 | 2022-07-31 00:00:10 |
| 9 | 2022-07-31 00:00:13 |

So, I need to label every 10 seconds based on the column "Time" by incremental value AS BELOW.

| ID | time | DESIRED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-31 23:59:53 | A |
| 2 | 2022-07-31 23:59:54 | A |
| 3 | 2022-07-31 23:59:55 | A |
| 4 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | B |
| 5 | 2022-08-01 00:00:01 | B |
| 6 | 2022-08-01 00:00:02 | B |
| 7 | 2022-08-01 00:00:07 | B |
| 8 | 2022-08-01 00:00:10 | C |
| 9 | 2022-08-01 00:00:13 | C |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably faster ways to do this but for me, the most intuitive method is to floor `time` into 10s-frequency column, encode the datetime into numbers and substitute the numbers into letters using `map()`.

```py
df['DESIRED_VALUE'] = (
    pd.Series(
        pd.to_datetime(df['time']) # convert the column to datetime (if it's not already)
        .dt.floor('10s')           # floor divide datetime with frequency of 10sec
        .factorize()[0],           # encode datetime into numbers
        index=df.index)            # construct a Series
    .map(dict(enumerate('ABC'))    # map letters to encoded numbers
        )
)
```

[image: res]